# Macro definition Error when compiling pcap

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to compile pcap but the macro definition can't pass:

```
#ifndef HAVE_STRLCPY
#define strlcpy(x, y, z) \
    (strncpy((x), (y), (z)), \
     ((z) <= 0 ? 0 : ((x)[(z) - 1] = '\0')), \
     strlen((y)))
#endif
```

> ./pcap-int.h:353:11: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...'
>   before '(' token

I'm using the *mips-openwrt-gcc* compiler.

It works fine with gcc.

I'm not good at macro in C.

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the actual line with the error.

Comment: VC2008 doesn't give an error on this macro

Comment: Not given error by VS

Comment: I'm using the mips-openwrt-gcc compiler, maybe that's problem.

Comment: How is `HAVE_STRLCPY` and how *should* `HAVE_STRLCPY` be defined? Have you run whatever the Windows equivalent of `./configure` is?

Comment: I need to use mips-openwrt-gcc, though gcc works fine.

Comment: It's much more likely something else you are including / not including is causing the issue, and/or `config.h` or equivalent is wrong.

Comment: same error here, I am using crosstools-ng compiled mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc, did you find a solution ?